# Is there a comprehensive list of tomcat roles?

Tags: tomcat

I want to have full access and control of tomcat to make my life simple for development. I am aware of the roles 'admin' and 'manager' and know there are a few more with hyphens such as 'manager-gui' but where can I find a comprehensive list with descriptions of the available roles? I can't even find a partial list in the documentation so anything close would be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **admin** and **manager** roles no longer exist in Tomcat 7+ and have been replaced by more specific roles.

For the Tomcat Manager application:

- **manager-gui**: allows access to the HTML GUI and the status pages
- **manager-script**: allows access to the text interface and the status pages
- **manager-jmx**: allows access to the JMX proxy and the status pages
- **manager-status**: allows access to the status pages only

For the Host Manager application:

- **admin-gui**: allows access to the HTML GUI and the status pages
- **admin-script**: allows access to the text interface and the status pages

Source: http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html